# Can someone explain the iOS "x-apple-msg-load://"?

Tags: ios

I'm sending emails from a Rails application.  The emails contain links like the following:

http://critically.in/events/14-san-francisco-ca-mc-hammer-bay-to-breakers

The URL is correct when I open it on my computer, but when I read it in Mail on my iPad or iPhone, the link is converted to:

x-apple-msg-load://90CEFE95-A78E-427F-B68E-EF184F497B69/critically.in/events/14-san-francisco-ca-mc-hammer-bay-to-breakers

Comment: Are you sure those links within your email are fully qualified and not relative links? Check the raw message text if the host-name/domain is actually mentioned.

Comment: Ah ha, I didn't have "http://" before the URL.  All my other mail clients (Facebook, too) corrected this for me.  But not iOS.  Good catch, Till!  Thanks!

Comment: Great - I will add this as an answer to prevent open questions...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure your links are actually fully qualified. That is, make sure they are containing the scheme and the entire domain-path.

- **bad**: ../blah/foo/bar
- **good**: http://example.com/blah/foo/bar

Relative URLs are not properly resolved by the iOS mail client and result into things looking like the issue you are describing.

To be absolutely certain, make sure you check the raw message text and not the results you see within other mail-clients.

Comment: To be totally clear, my particular problem was that I was missing the "http://" in the URL.  Thanks, Till!  (I tried to post my own answer but apparently I need to wait 8 hours?)

Comment: Also scheme in Mail.app in iOS6 can't starts with digit (2do2go: for example is invalid). In this case Mail.app broke link by adding x-apple-msg-load:// prefix.

Comment: I had the same problem when "smart" quotes were being used in HTML tags.